# Issues displaying images in Rails using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, carrierwave

I'm having issues displaying the thumbnail of my uploaded image. A file successfully uploads but I have been unable to display it. Any attempt to find the url or path throws undefined method errors. Really appreciate any and all help!

Model

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :profile_images, ImageUploader
end
```

controller

```
...
def play_params
    params.require(:play).permit(:title, :description, :date_of_play,:profile_image)
end
...
```

Uploader

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

views/plays/_form.html.erb

```
...
<%= f.file_field :profile_image %>
...
```

views/plays/show.html.erb

```
...
<%= image_tag @play.profile_image.url(:thumb) if @play.profile_image.present? %>
...
```

migration

```
class CreatePlays < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :plays do |t|
    t.string :title, null: false
    t.string :description, null: false
    t.datetime :date_of_play, null: false
    t.string :profile_image

    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

error

```
undefined method `url' for "#<File:0x00000005a7dbb8>":String
```

Thanks!

Comment: `mount_uploaders :profile_images, ImageUploader` should be `mount_uploader :profile_image, ImageUploader`.

Comment: OH MY GOD. You SAINT! Please answer my question so I can accept it and give some sweet, sweet points. I previously tried changing profile_images -> profile_image but never thought about mount_uploaders->mount_uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
mount_uploaders :profile_images, ImageUploader
```

to

```
 mount_uploader :profile_image, ImageUploader
```

Refer to the [CarrierWave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), you have just mixed up single and multiple file uploads configuration.

Comment: Thanks again! I spent hours on this...really appreciate it.